# Preserve side-effect and capture stdout and stderr of a bash function in separate variables?

Tags: bash

Suppose the bash function `dump` modifies a variable and prints different contents to `stdout` and `stderr`:

```
function dump() {
  var1=1
  echo OUT
  echo ERR 1>&2
}
```

The variable `var1` could be defined in the context of its caller or could be initially defined by the function itself. If `var1` is defined in the caller, the modification of `var1` inside the function `dump` should be propagated to the caller. If `var1` is initially defined inside `dump`, there are no requirements on whether `var1` should be propagated to the caller or not.

Given this bash script may run on a system where all mounted file systems are read-only and no tmpfs are mounted, the workaround of this problem should not employ any redirect to file operations. The script may run without root privilege or any capabilities. Commands like `unshare` may not work, as user namespaces are not permitted. You may also assume that the bash built-in network files `/dev/tcp` and `/dev/udp` are patched out.

Is there any way to capture the `stdout` and `stderr` of `dump` in different variables, while exposing variable modifications(the side effects)?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do it. To capture the output of a function in a variable, it has to run in a subshell, and that prevents any variable modifications from propagating to the parent shell. And capturing stdout and stderr separately is also difficult.

Comment: What about exporting variables from the function itself containing the contents of stdout/err instead of running it in a subshell ? Very hacky though

Comment: No, there is not.

Comment: Thanks for your guys' comment, though it's sad to hear that 

Comment: @TJM : You could capture stdout/stderr  and store it in variables **inside** your function. Since your variables are not declared `local`, they are accessible outside of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> s there any way to capture the stdout and stderr of dump in different variables, while exposing variable modifications(the side effects)?

Sure. Just use temporary files. For example:

```
stdoutf=$(mktemp)
stderrf=$(mktemp)
dump >"$stdoutf" 2>"$stderrf"
stderr=$(<"$stderrf")
sdtout=$(<"$stdoutf")
rm "$stderrf" "$stdoutf"
```

> file systems are read-only and no tmpfs are mounted

Many shell commands will stop working then. - shell primarily works on *files*, without files shell is hard. Still, I guess that `/dev/shm` has to be mounted, and you can use it as temporary place.

> not employ any redirect to file operations

Ugh, asking for trouble... Anyway, you can buffer data in subprocesses memory and transfer data with temporary fifos or just using shared memory. You can write a bash builtin to call `mmap()` and share the fd between processes and store data there and read from parent (I remember seeing sources of such a program on GitHub, but I can't find it now). Anyway, here's an example with handy coproc:

```
#!/bin/bash

dump() {
  var1=1
  echo OUT
  echo ERR 1>&2
}

bufferer() {
    stdout=""
    stderr=""
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        case "$line" in
        stderr*) stderr+=${line#stderr}$'\n'; ;;
        stdout*) stdout+=${line#stdout}$'\n'; ;;
        esac
    done
    cat <<<"$stdout"
    echo MARK
    cat <<<"$stderr"
}

coproc { bufferer; }

exec 9>&"${COPROC[1]}"
dump > >(xxd -p | sed 's/^/stdout/' >&9) 2> >(xxd -p | sed 's/^/stderr/' >&9)
eval "exec ${COPROC[1]}<&-"
exec 9>&-

out=$(cat <&"${COPROC[0]}")
eval "exec ${COPROC[0]}<&-"

stdout=$(printf "%s" "${out%MARK*}" | xxd -p -r)
stderr=$(printf "%s" "${out#*MARK}" | xxd -p -r)

declare -p var1 stdout stderr
```

the script outputs:

```
declare -- var1="1"
declare -- stdout="OUT"
declare -- stderr="ERR"
```